# What happens when EventLogEntry.Index reaches MaxInt?

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading the Application eventlog using Eventlog.Entries (c# .NET 4.0) to get the EventLogEntry-objects and do stuff with them. The EventLogEntry.Index property always seems to grow when new events are written to the eventlog. Clearing the eventlog does not reset the  EventLogEntry.Index.

What happens when EventLogEntry.Index reaches maxint? Does the operating system ever reset the index?

I am writing a service which will run on a server (win2008R2) and I must assume that there will be very much eventlogging going on. Eventually it will probably reach 2.1 billion and then what happens?

Comment: While you should know what happens when that actually happens, you'll be long past all practical use for so many log records. I would still set a [retention policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721981(v=ws.11).aspx) to make sure you have a manageable log size at all times. Also, you should consider if the EventLog is the proper sink for your log messages. Maybe another technique (log files, ring buffers, etc) is a better solution.

Comment: Even with an eventlog configured for overwriting events, giving a manageable log size the Index still grows. As I wrote, clearing the log does not reset the Index. The actual usage of this is to store select event logs in a SQL Server database for analysis and then archiving.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed the "Clearing the eventlog does not reset the EventLogEntry.Index" in your question, sorry. (Actually, that even seems to be [desired behavior](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/itmanagement/en-US/25c7bdba-258b-44e6-87ba-d40e68b6b4e2/resetting-the-eventrecordid-for-a-windows-2008-r2-event-log?forum=winservergen); which makes sense when thinking about it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EventLogEntry.Index` property is obtained via the Windows API from the `RecordNumber` field of [the EVENTLOGRECORD structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363646(v=vs.85).aspx).

[The documentation for `RecordNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363660(v=vs.85).aspx) explicitly states:

> The RecordNumber member of EVENTLOGRECORD contains the record number
>   for the event log record. The very first record written to an event
>   log is record number 1, and other records are numbered sequentially.
>   If the record number reaches ULONG_MAX, the next record number will be
>   0, not 1; however, you use zero to seek to the record.

Note that `ULONG_MAX` is a 'C' preprocessor value, and is in fact equivalent to C#'s `uint.MaxValue`, however confusing that may sound...

Also note that unfortunately `EventLogEntry.Index` returns this `uint` as an `int`, so when it exceeds 2^31 it will become negative.

If you want to make sure it works properly, you'll probably want to cast it to `uint` to make sure that values between 2^31 and 2^32-1 are handled correctly.

**To specifically answer your question "What happens when EventLogEntry.Index reaches MaxInt?":**

The next index after `MaxInt` will be `-2147483648`, and then `-2147483647` and so on until it reaches `-1` at which point it will wrap to `0` and then start counting up normally.

If, however, you cast the `int` to `uint` then the index will go from `1` to `uint.MaxValue` and THEN it will wrap back to `0`.